# More options in a Linux command and compilation error

Tags: c, linux, shell, compilation, command

I am trying to add as option in the command `$ printenv` the command `date` .  e.g. if you try to run `$ printenv -d`  it should return the date output.

I have the src code from the link `ftp://ftp.ntua.gr/pub/gnu/coreutils/coreutils-8.23.tar.xz` that contains all the coreutils in a linux distribution.

I have already change the source code of src/printenv.c (this file is in the coreutils.tar file). But what is my next move ?

I can not compile it with `gcc printenv.c`

```
Compile error: fatal error: config.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Should I make the makefiles/configs etc  and install it manually? How?

I post my changed code (printenv.c)

```
    /* printenv -- print all or part of environment
   Copyright (C) 1989-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

   This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
   the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
   (at your option) any later version.

   This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
   GNU General Public License for more details.

   You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
   along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.  */

/* Usage: printenv [variable...]

   If no arguments are given, print the entire environment.
   If one or more variable names are given, print the value of
   each one that is set, and nothing for ones that are not set.

   Exit status:
   0 if all variables specified were found
   1 if not
   2 if some other error occurred

   David MacKenzie and Richard Mlynarik */

#include <config.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <getopt.h>

#include "system.h"

/* Exit status for syntax errors, etc.  */
enum { PRINTENV_FAILURE = 2 };

/* The official name of this program (e.g., no 'g' prefix).  */
#define PROGRAM_NAME "printenv"

#define AUTHORS \
  proper_name ("David MacKenzie"), \
  proper_name ("Richard Mlynarik")

static struct option const longopts[] =
{
  {"null", no_argument, NULL, '0'},
  {"date", required_argument, NULL, 'd'},
  {GETOPT_HELP_OPTION_DECL},
  {GETOPT_VERSION_OPTION_DECL},
  {NULL, 0, NULL, 0}
};

/* Forward declarations.  */
static void dateMachine (void);

void
usage (int status)
{
  if (status != EXIT_SUCCESS)
    emit_try_help ();
  else
    {
      printf (_("\
Usage: %s [OPTION]... [VARIABLE]...\n\
Print the values of the specified environment VARIABLE(s).\n\
If no VARIABLE is specified, print name and value pairs for them all.\n\
\n\
"),
              program_name);
      fputs (_("\
  -0, --null     end each output line with NUL, not newline\n\
"), stdout);
      fputs (HELP_OPTION_DESCRIPTION, stdout);
      fputs (VERSION_OPTION_DESCRIPTION, stdout);
      printf (USAGE_BUILTIN_WARNING, PROGRAM_NAME);
      emit_ancillary_info ();
    }
  exit (status);
}

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  char **env;
  char *ep, *ap;
  int i;
  bool ok;
  int optc;
  bool opt_nul_terminate_output = false;

  initialize_main (&argc, &argv);
  set_program_name (argv[0]);
  setlocale (LC_ALL, "");
  bindtextdomain (PACKAGE, LOCALEDIR);
  textdomain (PACKAGE);

  initialize_exit_failure (PRINTENV_FAILURE);
  atexit (close_stdout);

  while ((optc = getopt_long (argc, argv, "+iu:0d", longopts, NULL)) != -1)
    {
      switch (optc)
        {
        case '0':
          opt_nul_terminate_output = true;
          break;
        case 'd':
          dateMachine ();
          break;
        case_GETOPT_HELP_CHAR;
        case_GETOPT_VERSION_CHAR (PROGRAM_NAME, AUTHORS);
        default:
          usage (PRINTENV_FAILURE);
        }
    }

  if (optind >= argc)
    {
      for (env = environ; *env != NULL; ++env)
        printf ("%s%c", *env, opt_nul_terminate_output ? '\0' : '\n');
      ok = true;
    }
  else
    {
      int matches = 0;

      for (i = optind; i < argc; ++i)
        {
          bool matched = false;

          /* 'printenv a=b' is silent, even if 'a=b=c' is in environ.  */
          if (strchr (argv[i], '='))
            continue;

          for (env = environ; *env; ++env)
            {
              ep = *env;
              ap = argv[i];
              while (*ep != '\0' && *ap != '\0' && *ep++ == *ap++)
                {
                  if (*ep == '=' && *ap == '\0')
                    {
                      printf ("%s%c", ep + 1,
                              opt_nul_terminate_output ? '\0' : '\n');
                      matched = true;
                      break;
                    }
                }
            }

          matches += matched;
        }

      ok = (matches == argc - optind);
    }

  exit (ok ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE);
}

static void
dateMachine (void)
{
    system(date);
}
```

Comment: You need to configure the coreutils source and then you can probably run `make printenv` (or similar). Try running `./configure`.

Comment: @EtanReisner  Question.. I want to compile it locally. I dont want to recompile the system printenv command.    

Also, : run : ./configure && make printenv
Result:   GEN      man/dynamic-deps.mk
make: *** No rule to make target `printenv'.  Stop.

Comment: `make printenv` was a guess. That may not be the actual target. `make` by itself will almost certainly build it (as well as everything else). And this won't do anything to the normal system `printenv` unless you copy it to the wrong place or use something incorrect like `./configure --prefix=/usr; make install` (don't do that).

Comment: Try `make src/printenv` maybe.

Comment: No `make src/printenv` doesn't work. I just tried that and it fails horribly. coreutils doesn't appear to be set up in a sane and correct fashion (good job people). Just run `make` and deal with it building everything else.

Comment: I cant run ./configure in guest mode or with a typical "test" user. It need sudoers permissions.  
Ah, great! I have to recompile all the coreutils.. I ll try a virtual machine. fss

 @EtanReisner

Comment: Running `./configure` should require *no* elevated permissions and in fact the configure script bails out and yells at you if you run it as root. Make sure you didn't extract the tarball as root or anything like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`./configure && make` (without sudo). It compiles every .c program locally.
It compiles only the .c files that have been changed, due to datestamp.

Answer (score 0):

If you google "printenv.c" You'll find several versions of just that file, that you can compile and run with minimal jiggery-pokery.

Example: "http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/shell_cmds/shell_cmds-170/printenv/printenv.c"